# Can I edit genesis.json file of ganache

Tags: genesis, ganache, truffle-config

I want to configure `ganache` for using proof of authorisation consensus mechanism instead of using proof of work. I want to edit `genesis.json` file for the same. I want to know where ganache stores its genesis.json file? Can I edit it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ganache is a development chain which is not able to use a different consensus mechanism. Ganache accepts all incoming transactions immediately and creates one block for each by default. You could describe it as proof-of-authority chain with just one node.

Ganache does not use a `genesis.json` file. 
The chain is defined by the options you pass to Ganache.
The --db option of the cli gives the possibility to store the chain and reload it later.